Is there a way to call reusable rules in javascript block as the following: testRigor.execute("my reusable rule with 'param1'")?
Trying to achieve the following but it ends up just blocking the server and never finishing the execution even when cancelling the test run:
    execute JavaScript text starting from next line and ending with [END]
        var tenantName = "Ford CSP";
        testRigor.execute('map tenant name "' + tenantName + '" to vinDecoder domain');
    [END]

To execute a resuable rule in a javaScript block.
Here is the unedited full reusable rule:
execute JavaScript text starting from next line and ending with [END]

var vinSeed = testRigor.getStoredValue('vinSeed');
var tenantName = testRigor.getStoredValue('tenantName');
await testRigor.execute('map tenant name "' + tenantName + '" to vinDecoder domain');
var vinDecoderDomain = testRigor.getStoredValue('vinDecoderDomain');
var i = 0;
var newModifiedVin = '';
var vinDecoderResponse = '';
var modelReturnedByVinDecoder = '';
var customerOriginValueFromRequestSession = '';
var mileageValueFromRequestSession = '';



while(i < 10){

    testRigor.execute('modify VIN "' + vinSeed + '" and return modified VIN as variable "newModifiedVin"');
    newModifiedVin = testRigor.getStoredValue('newModifiedVin');
    testRigor.execute('validate vin "' + newModifiedVin + '" for vin type "'+ vinDecoderDomain +'" on vin decoder');
    vinDecoderResponse = testRigor.getStoredValue("vinDecoderResponse");
    testRigor.execute('parse Json string "' + vinDecoderResponse + '" with the JsonPath "$.data.model" and save the result as "modelReturnedByVinDecoder"');
    modelReturnedByVinDecoder = testRigor.getStoredValue('modelReturnedByVinDecoder');

    if(modelReturnedByVinDecoder !== 'null'){
    
         testRigor.execute('request session endpoint call by request type "vin" with request data "'+ newModifiedVin +'" for tenant "'+ tenantName +'"');
         testRigor.execute('parse Json string "' + requestSessionResponse + '" with the JsonPath "$.data.customerOrigin" and save the result as "customerOriginValueFromRequestSession"');
         testRigor.execute('parse Json string "' + requestSessionResponse + '" with the JsonPath "$.data.vehicleInformation.mileage" and save the result as "mileageValueFromRequestSession"');
         customerOriginValueFromRequestSession = testRigor.getStoredValue("customerOriginValueFromRequestSession");
         mileageValueFromRequestSession = testRigor.getStoredValue("mileageValueFromRequestSession");
         
         if(customerOriginValueFromRequestSession === "Unknown" && mileageValueFromRequestSession === "0"){
             testRigor.putStoredValue('vin', newModifiedVin);
             break;
         }
    }
    vinSeed = newModifiedVin;
    i++;
}

[END]

There really isn't enough information here for anybody to offer much help. Nobody knows what it is you're trying to test or what it's supposed to do.

There may be a couple of issues causing the infinite execution that causes the hanging issue:

If the JavaScript block is trying to execute a rule that itself contains JavaScript that calls the same rule, it could create an infinite loop

The execute() command might need to be handled asynchronously


I suggest you try these approaches:
// Option 1: Use async/await
execute JavaScript text starting from next line and ending with [END]
    var tenantName = "Ford CSP";
    await testRigor.execute('map tenant name "' + tenantName + '" to vinDecoder domain');
[END]

// Option 2: Use a callback
execute JavaScript text starting from next line and ending with [END]
    var tenantName = "Ford CSP";
    testRigor.execute('map tenant name "' + tenantName + '" to vinDecoder domain', function(result) {
        // Handle the result here
        console.log('Rule execution completed');
    });
[END]

Do you mind sharing what’s inside the reusable rule you’re trying to execute?
And are you seeing any specific error massages in the logs?

Just added the full reusable rule on the question @Zeros-N-Ones! Other than that i tries using both the await and callback solutions you gave me but both make testRigor fail. The await solution failed when saving the resuableRule with the following error: ":20:14 Expected ; but found testRigor await testRigor.execute('fail with error "invalid search type"'); ^ in  at line number 20 at column number 14 during compilation of JavaScript: execute JavaScript text starting from next line and ending with [END] var tenantName = testRigor.getStoredValue("tenantName"); var requestType =..."

And the call back solution did save but during execution failed with the following: TypeError: Can not invoke method [jdk.dynalink.beans.SimpleDynamicMethod boolean com.testrigor.combinator.walker.javascript.TestRigorImpl.execute(String)] with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures. in  at line number 12
